# How to append multiple images in FormGroup

Tags: node.js, angular

In my angular app I have created an image gallery. Where I can insert multiple images together. I am using `FormGroup` to get the values of the form. I am finished with all other `formControls` and stucking in here where I have too `append` the images to my fromControl.

[image]

When I `console.log(this.images)` I can see all the `images` data, But if I try `console.log(this.gallery.value)` after picking the images. I can see only one image. It's like `{images: File}` only one file is present. I have tried

```
 this.gallery = new FormGroup({
      images : new FormControl([this.images])
    })
```

Here is my `.ts` file.

```
 images : any = [];
 gallery : FormGroup;

 onGalleryPicked(event : Event){
    const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
    this.gallery.patchValue({images : file});
    this.gallery.get('images').updateValueAndValidity();
    // console.log(file);
    // console.log(this.images);
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e: any) =>{
        if(this.images.length < 4){
          this.images.push(e.target.result);
        }
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
   }
  removeImg(image : any){
    this.images = this.images.filter((a)=>a !== image)
  }

  this.gallery = new FormGroup({
      images : new FormControl()
    })
```

and here's the `template` :

```
<form [formGroup]="gallery">
            <!-- form image -->
            <div class="product-gallery">
              <div class="product-gallery">
                <button (click)="galleryPick.click()" mat-button>
                  Upload Images*
                </button>
                <input type="file" #galleryPick (change)="onGalleryPicked($event)" />
              </div>
              <div class="gallery-images">
                <div class="small-images" *ngFor="let image of images">
                  <img [src]="image" alt="">
                  <span><button (click)="removeImg(image)">x</button></span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
              <button mat-flat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
            </div>
   </form>
```

Now my problem is I want to append `this.images` inside the `formControl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use **formArray** conecpt of forms to do this. You can use the formArray to create array of form and contain a single image in each form.

Comment: Can you demonstrate how will I implement `FormArray` in this case?